# Update stock value with mysql

Tags: mysql

Now i have this sql update code:

```
$sql = "UPDATE products SET stock = stock - '$quantity' WHERE product_id = '$id'";
```

I have some problem with this. It works, but if the stock value in the table is smaller, than the quantity in the webshop cart, it will update the stock field to a minus value.

I know, that there is a function in mysql for this, that will only update it to 0, and not to minus. Whats that function, or how should i do this?

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Answer (score 3):

You can use case

```
UPDATE products SET stock 
  = case
     when stock > '$quantity' then stock - '$quantity' 
     else 0 end
WHERE product_id = '$id';
```

Be sure that your variables `$quantity` and `$id` are checked to be sure that they are numeric to avoid SQL injection.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **[MySQL IF Statement](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_if.asp)** for this. First check if `stock - quantity` is greater than 0 then return the value, else return 0.

```
UPDATE products
SET stock = IF(stock - '$quantity' > 0, stock - '$quantity', 0) 
WHERE product_id = '$id';
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [GREATEST](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) function to get the largest value of your existing calculation or 0, then if the current calculation is negative, 0 will be inserted.

I haven't tested this, but this should work:

```
$sql = "UPDATE products SET stock = GREATEST(stock - '$quantity', 0) WHERE product_id = '$id'";
```

I'd just be careful you aren't prone to SQL injection here as you are passing `$quantity` and `$id` directly to the query string and if this is from a `$_POST` or `$_GET` request variable then the query can be manipulated.